# How to call rails 3 model method in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, console

I have a method in a rails 3 model that parses XML with nokogiri.
How can I call this method in the console in order to test its out.

Here is the whole class (I'm trying to call generate_list):

```
class Podcast < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_uniqueness_of :name

serialize :hosts

def generate_list

# fetch the top 300 podcasts from itunes
itunes_top_300 = Nokogiri.HTML(open("http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=300/explicit=true/xml"))

# parse the returned xml
itunes_top_300.xpath('//feed/entry').map do |entry|
  new_name = entry.xpath("./name").text
  podcast = Podcast.find(:all, :conditions => {:name => new_name})
  if podcast.nil?
    podcast = Podcast.new(
      :name => entry.xpath("./name").text,
      :itunesurl => entry.xpath("./link/@href").text,
      :category => entry.xpath("./category/@term").text,
      :hosts => entry.xpath("./artist").text,
      :description => entry.xpath("./summary").text,
      :artwork => entry.xpath("./image[@height='170']").text      
    )
    podcast.save
  else
    podcast.destroy
  end
end

end

end
```

Edit: Wow, 1000 views.  I hope this question has helped people as much as it helped me.  It's amazing to me when I look back on this that, little more than a year ago, I couldn't figure out the difference between instance methods and class methods.  Now I am writing complex service-oriented applications and backends in ruby, Rails, and many other languages/frameworks.  **Stack Overflow is the reason for this.  Thank you so much to this community for empowering people to solve their problems and understand their solutions.**

Comment: Please show us how this method is defined.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like you're wanting to use this as a class method, and so you must define it like this:

```
def self.generate_list
  ...
end
```

Then you can call this as `Podcast.generate_list`.

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: What if the method takes arguments?

Comment: @bcackerman Then call it however you would call a method that takes arguments: `Podcast.generate_list(arg1, arg2)`

Comment: Thanks!  Have to make sure to `reload!` after making code changes

Answer (score 15):

From your code, it looks like your `generate_list` method actually builds the Podcast and saves it?

Start up the rails console:
`$ rails console`

And create a new Podcast, calling the method on it:

```
> pod = Podcast.new
> pod.generate_list
```

Comment: Or convert it into an instance method as others have mentioned with `def self.generate_list`

Comment: This worked exactly right.  Make sure to "reload!" if you change the code.  Self. didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Or, if you don't want to rewrite your code, follow this.

Type `rails c` on the terminal to open the console, then just do:

```
p = Podcast.new
p.generate_list
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an instance method so try:

```
Podcast.first.generate_list
```

You should make a class method by declaring it as follows:

```
def self.generate_list
```

And call it:

```
Podcast.generate_list
```